# How can I make a simple mouseon popup tooltip with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to show related tooltip for listed info, related *tooltip* and info are in same cell in table. I don't want use a plugin for this.

When `onmouseover` to any link, related tooltip displayed and if `onmouseover` to tooltip box, tooltip box will not close. When `onmouseout` any area on page except tooltip box or related link, tooltip box will close.

I want to make a simple tooltip as like this [plugin](http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/). Is there a simple way for this without using a plugin?

**HTML**

```
<table width="600">
<tr>
    <td>                                  
        <a href="#" class="link">Link-1</a>
        <div class="tooltip">(1) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>                        
        <a href="#" class="link">Link-2</a>
        <div class="tooltip">(2) when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>                        
        <a href="#" class="link">Link-3</a>
        <div class="tooltip">(3) It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>                        
        <a href="#" class="link">Link-4</a>
        <div class="tooltip">(4) publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table td {
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:50px;
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('.link').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).next().show();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).next().hide();   
        }
    )   
})
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/96j44/

Comment: Try removing the `.hide()` and use `.mouseenter()` to show it. Then to close it target both `.link` and `.tooltip` on the `.mouseout()` event.

Comment: No Javascript or jQuery necessary, just css http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/9kBVu/

Comment: @Xotic750 Sorry, but that doesn't seem to be the question. The tooltip should stay visible after the mouseover

Comment: Ok that part of the question didn't register, but it does the same as his jQuery example. I didn't see that he wanted it to be "sticky". I'm sure there are lots of answers here on SO.

Comment: @midstack Almost got it... seems to only do the propper "thing" on tooltip4, can't see why, but I'll keep at it after dinner. Catch you in a bit and good luck. http://jsfiddle.net/ZeNz0r/96j44/3/

Comment: @FernandoSilva thank you but not exactly what I want. I want to close tooltip when mouseout link or tooltip box, but if mouseover on tooltip box, box will not close

Comment: yes I know that, but this works with using plugin (for example: http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/ (Mouse on to popup example).) But I don't want to use any plugin for this and I asked for an easy way of doing this without using plugin @Xotic750

Comment: @midstack try Link-4 it won't close, only when you leave the tooltip. Going to try and see why the rest isn't doing the same.

Comment: Is there any reason for the `table` in your example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An easy or simple way to do this, without a jQuery plugin, is by adding some simple rules to your CSS, and then no Javascript or jQuery is necessary. I don't really understand your need for the `table` though, and the CSS would be simpler if your were not using one.

```css
table td {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50px;
  display: none;
}

.tooltip {
  z-index: 100;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  width: 9%;
}

.link:hover+.tooltip {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table width="600">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="link">Link-1</a>
      <div class="tooltip">(1) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="link">Link-2</a>
      <div class="tooltip">(2) when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="link">Link-3</a>
      <div class="tooltip">(3) It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="link">Link-4</a>
      <div class="tooltip">(4) publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Fernando Silva Updated answer now the problem has become clearer, please check now and look at your voting.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Anyone could missread this question. I will upvote you though, that is a clean solution. And I just learned about the + in CSS as well, gotta read up on it^^

Comment: No problem, I thought it was you as it happened while we discussed it. I apologise.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Since you were using a table, the `td`'s were above the `.tooltip`'s and the mouseout event was triggered before time.

So basically you need to add `z-index:1;` or higher depending on the surroundings to avoid that problem.

And your jQuery would be like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.link').on('mouseenter',
        function () {
            //if a tooltip is visible hide it so the right one can show up
            if ($('.tooltip').is(':visible')) {
                $('.tooltip').hide();
            }
            $(this).next().show();
    });
    $('.tooltip').on('mouseout',
        function () {
            $(this).hide();
    });
})
```

Here's a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeNz0r/96j44/6/), highlighted the `td`'s in case you want to take out the z-index and see what was going on.

Comment: you need to add table mouseleave event as well, so if you move the mouse below link 4, it would hide tooltip.

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz roger that, i'll try to fit it in, when i get to work. Thks^^

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz I just saw what you mean, but adding the table, like this `$('.tooltip, table').on('mouseout'...` and then `$('.tooltip').hide()` so the table doesn't hide just hides the tooltip too soon. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeNz0r/96j44/7/

Comment: Downvoting and not explaining, won't help me learn. I don't mind the downvote, but not knowing why doesn't let me improve in any way :(

Comment: One would assume because of the comment that @Caner Akdeniz left.

Comment: i didnt downvote, i was actually surprised why it was downvoted. your solution is working pretty well. just neede couple tweaks.

Comment: Did you get any further with tweaking this solution?

Comment: @Xotic750 Not yet, need to get a selector for the mouseout event that hides the tooltip if the mouse leaves `.tooltip` or `table` but ´.tooltip table´ and ´.tooltip, table´ aren't working since the 1st means a table with that class, and the second fires as soon as he leaves the anchor. Haven't had much time, but I'm trying to get there.